# Trouble parsing a select element

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown in a Grid. This is how it looks like.  Now I am
    trying to get the name of the select tag.
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('select'); 
I need to get the name and
    parse it in such a way to get this value **13442111**. What's the best way to go about getting this information?

```
<td class="cl">
    <select name="ctrlvcol%3DId%3Bctrl%3DTabListView%3Brow%3D13442111%3Btype%3Dtxt" onchange="getTypeValue(this.value,13442111)">
       <option value="1025">TEST-AAAA</option>
       <option selected="" value="1026">TEST-BBBB</option>
       <option value="1027">TEST-CCCC</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: unescape("ctrlvcol%3DId%3Bctrl%3DTabListView%3Brow%3D13442111%3Btype%3Dtxt").split("row=")[1].split(";")[0]

Comment: Is this the only `select` element in the document? If not, how are you distinguishing it from the others?

Comment: If the name is unknown you probably want a more precise way of retrieving the element.  I suggest tagging it with an id or class.

Comment: In what context are you trying to get the name of this? and will there be other dropdowns? and are you doing this iteratively so that you will be retrieving these values for all the dropdowns?

Comment: How is the name being generated?  It is certainly possible to parse the name with a regex but in order to do that you need to know the constants in order to formulate a pattern.

Comment: @Bergi No, There are 10 rows in the grid and each row will be having 5 dropdowns and 2 text fields. Each dropdown will be distinguished by this 'Id'..Each dropdown will have different Id's ctrlvcol%3D**Id**% but for a particular row this value '13442111' will be the same, for another row the value will be different.

Comment: @Venkat: So you're not trying to get the id out of a select element you already know, but to get the select element whose name contains a certain id?

Comment: @Bergi I need to get the particular row on which I am editing. So I am passing the id in onchange(id) method and checking it with this parsed value. Though I am getting parsed value from the select ,but I couldn't able to get the row on which I am editing. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bit of code that may help you. This little snippet will work **if and only if** this is the only `select` element on the page. As the comments above state, it would be better to identify this element with an `id`. However, for your use case the following should work:

```
// Get all select elements (in this case the one) on the page.
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

// Select the first "select" element and retrieve the "name" attribute from it
var nameAttr = decodeURIComponent(elems[0].getAttribute("name"));

// Split the decoded name attribute on the ";" and pull the second index (3rd part)
var nameProp = nameAttr .split(';')[2];

// Substr the name prop from the equal sign to the the end
nameProp = nameProp.substr(nameProp .indexOf('=') + 1);
```

Comment: @Venkat If by API function, you mean a standard JavaScript built in function, then yes. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) is the Mozilla Developer Network page on it...

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var selectElementsLen = selectElements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < selectElementsLen; i++) {

    // split row parts
    var rowID = unescape(selectElements[i].name).split(';');
    if (rowID.length >= 3) {

        // trim meta
        rowID = rowID[2].replace(/^row=/, '');

        // validate row ID
        if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(rowID)) {
            console.log('Valid Row ID: ' + rowID);
            // do whatever needs to be done
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N4sJv/

Here's the approach with regular expression only:

```
var selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var selectElementsLen = selectElements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < selectElementsLen; i++) {

    // extract Row ID
    var rowID = unescape(selectElements[i].name).match(/(?:row=)([0-9]+)/);
    if (rowID && (rowID.length >= 2)) {
        rowID = rowID[1];
        console.log('Valid Row ID: ' + rowID);
        // do whatever needs to be done
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N4sJv/1/

Keep in mind that document.getElementsByTagName() may not be the best choice as it selects all specified elements in the DOM tree. You might want to use a framework such as jQuery to consider browser compatibilities and performance.

Comment: If I use a JQuery what will be the advantage?

Comment: You can optimize the selector with it. document.getElementsByTagName() will basically iterate through the DOM tree and check each element regardless of its level in the tree. Using the jQuery selector "td.cl select" would skip all elements that are not children of a td element. This is probably overkill for your use case, but it might out-perform on bigger DOM trees.